# How to find number of numerical data for each and every line in a file

Tags: text-processing, perl

Please help me to count the numerical data in each line of a file,
and also to find the line length. The code has to written in Perl.
For example if I have a line such as:

```
INPUT:I was born on 24th october,1994.
Output:2
```

Comment: Here the numerical data refers to a sequence of digits like 1947 .

Comment: sample input: మోతీలాల్ నెహ్రూ (ఆంగ్లం : Motilal Nehru) (మే 6, 1861 – ఫిబ్రవరి 6, 1931). భారతీయ స్వాతంత్ర్య సమర యోధుడు మరియు భారత జాతీయ కాంగ్రెస్ నాయకుడు. ఇతను, బలీయమైన రాజకీయ కుటుంబ స్థాపకుడు.                                   output: 4 (8,1861,6,1931)

Comment: Please put additional information in the question, not in comments. Also, the question is unclear. Are you asking for the number of characters in your line which are numeric? Or are you asking for the number of distinct numeric substrings that are contained in a line?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```bsh
perl -ne 'BEGIN{my $x} $x += () = /[0-9]+/g; END{print($x . "\n")}' file
```

- `-n`: causes Perl to assume the following loop around your program, which makes it iterate over filename arguments somewhat like sed -n or awk:

  ```perl
  LINE:
    while (<>) {
        ...             # your program goes here
    }
  ```
- `-e`: may be used to enter one line of program;
- `()` will make `/[0-9]+/g` be evaluated in list context (i.e. `() = /[0-9]+/g` will return an array containing the sequences of one or more digits found in the default input), while `$x +=` will make the result be evaluated again in scalar context (i.e. `$x += () = /[0-9]+/g` will add the number of sequences of one or more digits found in the default input to `$x`); `END{print($x . "\n")` will print `$x` after the whole file has been processed.

```bsh
% cat file
string 123 string 1 string string string
456 string
% perl -ne 'BEGIN{my $x} $x += () = /[0-9]+/g; END{print($x . "\n")}' file
3
%
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $file = 'num.txt';

open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Failed to open $file: $!\n";

while (my $line = <$fh>){
    chomp $line;
    my @num = $line =~ /([0-9.]+)/g;
    print "On this line --- " .scalar(@num) . "\n";
}
close ($fh);
```

The input file I tested --

```
This should say 1
Line 2 should say 2
I want this line to say 5 so I have added 4 other numbers like 0.02 -1 and 5.23
```

The output as tested ----

```
On this line --- 1
On this line --- 2
On this line --- 5
```

Using the regex match ([0-9.]+) will match ANY number and include any decimals (I guess really you could use just ([0-9]+) since you are only counting them and not using the actually number represented.)

Hope it helps.